# Prove that a family of mollifiers converges in $L_\text{loc}^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

Let $B_1$ be the open ball with radius $1$ around $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,\infty)$ with

1. $\phi\in C_0^\infty(B_1)$, i.e. $\phi$ is infinitely many differentiable in $B_1$ and vanishes at infinity
2. $\phi\equiv 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\overline{B}_1$
3. $\int\phi d\lambda^n=1$, where $\lambda^n$ is the Lebesgue measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Now, let $$\phi_\varepsilon(x):=\frac 1{\varepsilon^n}\phi\left(\frac x\varepsilon\right)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb{R}^n$$ for $\varepsilon>0$. I want to show, that $$\phi_\varepsilon\to 0\;\text{in }L_\text{loc}^\infty\left(B_1\setminus\left\{0\right\}\right)\text{ as }\varepsilon\to 0\tag{1},$$ where $L^p_\text{loc}(\Omega)$ is the space of all $p$-times locally integrable functions.

---

I've got problems to understand what exactly is meant by $(1)$. From the definition of local integrability and $L^\infty$, we should have $f_n\stackrel{L_\text{loc}^\infty(\Omega)}{\to}0$ iff $$\forall K\subseteq\Omega\text{ compact }:\operatorname{ess sup}\limits_{K}|f_n|\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}0$$
for any $(f_n:\Omega\to\mathbb{R})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, where $\operatorname{ess sup}$ is the *essential supremum*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ be compact. Let
$$
d=\min_{x\in K}|x|
$$
be the distance from the origin to $K$; then $d>0$.  From the properties of $\phi$, $\phi_\epsilon(x)=0$ if $|x|>\epsilon$. If $0<\epsilon<d$, then $\phi_\epsilon(x)=0$ for all $x\in K$. Thus
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\operatorname{ess sup}\limits_{K}|\phi_\epsilon|=0.
$$

Comment: $\phi(x)=0$, if $|x|>1$. So, shouldn't we have $\phi_\varepsilon(x)=0$, if $|x|>\varepsilon$?

Comment: Yes. Typo corected.